# Is there an Android development board that can handle the latest Android versions?

Tags: android

I'm starting on android development. I've developed a pair of applications for mobile devices, but now I have to go deeper. I have to develop a custom room for a custom board that in the future could be something like a tablet.

I have a development kit, but it works with a custom android rom v3.2.7. I'm looking for a development kit or something like this, that can handle the latest android versions and that is up to date. I'm looking for this but I only found development boards with old custom rooms that doesnst seem that will be updated.

So, does someone know about something like this?

Comment: Voting to close as tool rec. You may have better chance at: http://android.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are ports of Android 4.2 for [BeagleBone Black](http://beagleboard.org/products/beaglebone%20black). BeagleBone (+Black) is based on AM335x from [TI](http://www.ti.com/lsds/ti/arm/sitara_arm_cortex_a_processor/sitara_arm_cortex_a8/am335x_arm_cortex_a8/getting_started.page?DCMP=AM33x_Announcement&HQS=am335x) and they provide quite support for it. Black has 512MB ram, 2GB mmc and runs on Cortex-A8 clocked to 1Ghz + NEON support. Recent Android versions optimizes for ram and I'm pretty much sure it should be able to be compatible with latest Android releases for a year.

Comment: looks nice! I'll consider as a great option, but.. is there something more powerfull? I don't care if I have to pay more. I need bluetooth and other functionality to be available

Comment: @masmic_87 I think with Android support is more important than power.

Comment: Well, I didn't mean more power as a better micro or more memory. I'm just a bit confused on what I really need to do, i don't know if i must consider this as a device or as an accessory. The reason why I say this is because i would need the board to have an LCD, bluetooth, etc. I suppose that would be the option of conecting this externally, but would be easier in the other way

Answer (score 0):

If you need a more powerfull board, you can have a look on [ODROID boards](http://www.hardkernel.com/main/main.php).